# Debugging linked DataLayers in Logi Info

Tags: debugging

I have a website built with Logi Info. It keeps logging errors with the following message:

> Unable to find the DataLayer for DataLayer.Linked . Set the LinkID to
> the ID of a DataLayerLink element. If the DataLayer is defined in
> another report definition, ensure that the Target element's
> LinkDataLayers = "True".

There does not seem to be a pattern as to what page or user action triggers this error. The only solution I can think of is to read through all the Logi report XML files line by line to find a DataLayer.Linked element with a reference to a DataLayer that does not exist.

What is the best way to go about debugging this error?

Does anyone have experience or advice dealing with Logi Info errors?

#### Update:

I read through one of the files that was causing errors and confirmed that there were no DataLayer.Linked elements referencing nonexistant DataLayer elements.

What else could be causing this error message?

Comment: Boric, If you are still experiencing this issue could you provide some example references in your code? Without a little more detail I can share what I've done in the past, but it would be little better than a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to read the files that are causing errors. Just try to open the report file (.lgx) source and look for a datalayer of type Linked as below

```
<DataLayer
    LinkedDataLayerID="This is your link ID which cannot be found"
    Type="Linked"
/>
```

Once you found it, check LinkedDataLayerID if exists. If doesn't exists that is your problem, If exists though, make sure is loaded before your DataLayer Linked element.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I tried creating group filters and sub-dataTables with the drop down menu. But when I type the column directly into the attribute, I have no problem running the definitions. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a Data Layer Link element to your local datalayer? It seems like you forgot to do that. Check this link out on devnet!
http://devnet.logianalytics.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=2047&dnProd=2